# How to compare fields from different collections in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

Here, I have multiple fields from multiple tables those values needs to compared and need to display desired result.

SQL QUERY:

```
select pd.service_id,ps.service_id from player pd, service ps where pd.subject_id=ps.subject_id and pd.service_id = ps.service_id
```

Mongo query:

```
db.player.aggregate([
        {
          "$lookup":{
            "from":"service",
            "localField":"player.subject_id",
            "foreignField":"subject_id",
            "as":"ps"
          }
        },
        {
          "$unwind":"$ps"
        },
        {
          "$match":{
           "service_id":{
            "$eq": "ps.service_id"
           }
          }
        }  
      ];
```

sample input records:

player:

```
[{subject_id:23,service_id:1},{subject_id:76,service_id:9}]
```

service:

```
[{subject_id:76,service_id:9},{subject_id:99,service_id:10}]
```

The match is not working. I have to match service_id's of both collections. Need to get matched records. But not able to see any result. Can anyone please help me to find out the mistake...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your query, if you want to compare 2 values from the document itself, you need to use [$expr](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) operator

```
{
    "$match":{
       "$expr":{
            "$eq": ["$service_id", "$ps.service_id"]
       }
    }
}
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/H95InjFDsLD)

**Alternative solution:** You need to use [Uncorrelated sub-query](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#std-label-lookup-uncorrelated-subquery) to "* join" with 2 o more conditions

```
db.player.aggregate([
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "service",
      "let": {
        subject_id: "$subject_id",
        service_id: "$service_id"
      },
      "pipeline": [
        {
          $match: {
            $expr: {
              $and: [
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$subject_id",
                    "$subject_id"
                  ]
                },
                {
                  $eq: [
                    "$$service_id",
                    "$service_id"
                  ]
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "as": "ps"
    }
  },
  // Remove non matched results
  {
    $match: {
      "ps.0": {
        $exists: true
      }
    }
  },
  // Remove temporal "ps" field
  {
    $addFields: {
      "ps": "$$REMOVE"
    }
  }
])
```

[MongoPlayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/JP06lSL4-cQ)

Comment: Thanks for your answer it helped out. But I have one more query There are duplicate subject_id's in my data. Can you please tell me How should I remove duplicates along with match condition

Comment: @Neel Hi. Share your duplicate inpu data in MongoPlayground and I'll what can we do

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72703539/how-to-combine-group-and-project-in-mongodb Please check this